# Let $x_n, a_n$ sequences. Prove $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} a_nx_n$ converges when $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} ||x_n||$ conv. & $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|<\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences, absolute-convergence

Real Analysis.
Hello, im taking a Real Analysis course and I'm trying to finish this proof given as an exercise.

Question:
Let $(X,||\cdot||)$ be a normed space. Let $x_n \subseteq X, a_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be sequences, asuch that $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} ||x_n||$ converges.  Suppose that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}|a_n|<\infty$

PROVE that $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} a_nx_n$ converges

My attempt: I know about the Cauchy convergence criterion, the definition we studied in class was:
$\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty} a_n$ converges if and only if $||\sum_{k=n} ^{m} a_k|| < \epsilon$, given an $\epsilon>0$ if $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such taht $\forall m,n \geq N$ $||\sum_{k=n} ^{m} a_k|| < \epsilon$.

Thus, usting the triangular inequality, I have that $||\sum_{k=n} ^{m} a_kx_k|| \leq \sum_{k=n} ^{m} ||a_kx_k||$.

Now, by properties of the Norm $||\sum_{k=n} ^{m} a_kx_k|| \leq \sum_{k=n} ^{m} |a_k|||x_k||$.

Now, my professor said that this property might be useful: " If $\alpha =\limsup_{n\to\infty}|b_n|$ and given an $\epsilon >0$ there are only **finite** "n´s" such that $b_n>\alpha + \epsilon$. However, I'm not too sure on how to use this...

I know that I need to in some sense "bound" $\sum_{k=n} ^{m} ||x_n||< \epsilon_1$, for some $\epsilon_1$....

Please any help is useful... Thanks in advance !!

Comment: The point of your professor's hint is that for all but finitely many $n, \vert a_n \vert \lt \alpha + 37.4$.   Take the maximum of the finitely many $\vert a_n \vert$ that exceed that bound, and you'll have a finite bound that applies to all $\vert a_n \vert$.  That means the $a_n$ are bounded.

Comment: You'll need to assume that $X$ is complete in order to use Cauchy's criterion.